# сортировка stooge sort

Tags: c++, сортировка

Нашел алгоритм сортировки StoogeSort

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void StoogeSort(int a[], int start, int end) {
    int temp;
    if (end - start + 1 > 2) {
        temp = (end - start + 1) / 3;
        StoogeSort(a, start, end - temp);
        StoogeSort(a, start + temp, end);
        StoogeSort(a, start, end - temp);
    }
    if (a[end] < a[start]) {
        temp = a[start];
        a[start] = a[end];
        a[end] = temp;
    }
}
```

Но не могу понять почему именно так используется строчка:  "if (end - start + 1 > 2)"

Answer (score 0):

Объяснение по этой сортировке можно прочитать на Википедии: [Stooge sort](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stooge_sort)

## Вот краткое объяснение:

Если в массиве 3 и более элементов, то:

1. вызываем сортировку для первых 2/3 массива
2. вызываем сортировку для вторых 2/3 массива
3. опять вызываем сортировку для первых 2/3 массива.

Если в массиве <3 элементов, то:
если первый элемент > последнего, меняем их местами

Comment: А в чем отличие, по вашему: `temp = (end - start + 1) / 3;` и `temp = int((end - start + 1) / 3);`? Это же эквивалентные выражения

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch извините, ошибся. Не учел, что в С++ деление и так целочисленное, если оба операнда целочисленные. Исправил.