# stooge sort сортировка

Tags: c++, сортировка

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void StoogeSort(int a[], int start, int end) {
    int temp;
    if (end - start + 1 > 2) {
        temp = (end - start + 1) / 3;
        StoogeSort(a, start, end - temp);
        StoogeSort(a, start + temp, end);
        StoogeSort(a, start, end - temp);
    }
    if (a[end] < a[start]) {
        temp = a[start];
        a[start] = a[end];
        a[end] = temp;
    }
}
```

помогите понять как это работает

Comment: Зачем делать второй вопрос? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1089155/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-stooge-sort

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых у вас в коде ошибка:

вместо `temp = (end - start + 1) / 3;` должно быть `temp = int((end - start + 1) / 3);`

Объяснение по этой сортировке можно прочитать на Википедии: [Stooge sort](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stooge_sort)

## Вот краткое объяснение:

Если в массиве 3 и более элементов, то:

1. вызываем сортировку для первых 2/3 массива
2. вызываем сортировку для вторых 2/3 массива
3. опять вызываем сортировку для первых 2/3 массива.

Если в массиве <3 элементов, то:
если первый элемент > последнего, меняем их местами